# How can I structure this app to avoid making redundant requests to the server?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

Disclaimer: I'm new to ember.

I'm trying to figure out how best to architect my app and have been at it for the last couple of afternoons. I am working on porting a large existing app over to ember mainly as an exercise to learn the framework.

To better illustrate my questions I have created a jsFiddle containing my entire app, backed by an instance of my API deployed on heroku: http://jsfiddle.net/dustmason/8fHmn/

To get the general idea, log in using the email and password noted on the fiddle, then click one of the project names.

Here's where I'm having trouble:

- The way I have the topBar controller/views/templates set up, ember-data makes a fresh request to the `/projects` endpoint of my api each time a project is visited. Why is that? What is a better way to structure this?
- Right now I am storing the current user's auth token as a property on my main `App` object. This feels wrong, but I've been unable to find a way to avoid this. What is a better way to handle this?

Answer (score 2):

> The way I have the topBar controller/views/templates set up, ember-data makes a fresh request to the /projects endpoint of my api each time a project is visited. Why is that?

Because the `setupController` hook is calling `App.Project.find()`, which triggers a query.

What is a better way to structure this?

Use `App.Project.all()` instead. See [Ember-Data .find() vs .all() - how to control cache?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16536925/ember-data-find-vs-all-how-to-control-cache)

> Right now I am storing the current user's auth token as a property on my main App object. This feels wrong, but I've been unable to find a way to avoid this. What is a better way to handle this?

There is nothing wrong with that approach (sometimes simple is best) but for a more elegant solution check out the latest embercast: http://www.embercasts.com/episodes/client-side-authentication-part-2

Comment: Thanks Mike. Very helpful. I followed the very well done 2 part embercasts series on auth while adding authentication to my app.

Comment: Changing find() to all() in the setupController method means that the Project model doesn't call the server at all. Where do you think would be a good place for an initial call to find()?