# Ember-Data - Find() not caching results from Rails API call

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I am brand new to Ember, and am having trouble with getting Ember/Ember Data to cache the results of an API call to the Rails backend.

I found this topic: [Ember-Data .find() vs .all() - how to control cache?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16536925/ember-data-find-vs-all-how-to-control-cache)

Which answered a few questions about what find() vs all() does, using that I found a workaround which looks ugly and I am wondering if there is a better, more concise way than this:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function () {
    if (this.store.all('facility').get('content.length')) {
      return this.store.all('facility');
    } else {
      return this.store.find('facility');
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of notes:

1. You shouldn't cache data inside model hook. Pass cached data with `#link-to` or similar API.
2. You shouldn't cache data at all if you don't have a notification system to tell Ember a resource has been changed. Keep in mind that your app may run for a very long time.
3. You can also do both at same time.

Here is an example to use cached data and update them in background. (Not tested)

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function () {
    var currentData = this.store.all('facility');
    this.store.find('facility'); // Ember automatically picks new changes

    return currentData;
  }
});
```

Comment: This works well thank you. The database the rails API pulls from will probably change at most once per year, do you think this is still the most efficient way?

Comment: @IanAndersen In that case you can consider server generated content with far in future expire headers. Do you have a lot of data?

Comment: It's not that much, about 8000 records that get returned, so I think the method you suggested will work just fine, just curious for learning purposes.

Comment: Try planning your sideloaded content, at this scale you can implement a pretty darn good user experience without a lot of effort. Keep an eye for server rendered ember if performance is important to you.